# How to change the DNS Zone nameserver in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, nameservers, azure-dns

How do I change the nameserver in a Microsoft Azure DNS Zone to be something else? I'd like to use Cloudflare for my nameservers instead of the default Azure ones.

[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Azure dashboard showing default DNS nameservers and no option to change them]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not change Microsoft azure DNS name server. [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-overview) is a hosting service for DNS domains that provides name resolution by using Microsoft Azure infrastructure. But Azure DNS supports **co-hosting domains** with other DNS services.

To set up co-hosting, modify the NS records for the domain to point to the name servers of both providers. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-faq#can-i-co-host-a-domain-by-using-azure-dns-and-another-dns-provider).

For example, you can add name servers from Cloudflare in the `additional name servers` in the NS record on the Azure portal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Name Server (NS) update are done on the domain registrar side.  In 'Azure DNS', Microsoft just manages the domain they are not the registrar.

If you want Cloud Flare to manage your domain the NS record needs to be change on the domain registrar side.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you bought an Azure App Service Domain, you get a DNS Zone (mine didn't work properly, and that's how I got to my solution). You also get a second resource from the domain itself (the App Service Domain resource). If you there click on the tab Advanced Management portal you will be redirected to a different site. From there you can go to the DNS tab at the top, select Manage Zones and fill in the domain you want to control.

From there, scroll down, and you'll see something like this.

[image: Nameservers]

As you can see, there are two nameservers. Those nameservers point to Azures DNS system. But here, you can actually change the nameservers.

Comment: Not sure if this is still possible. I know some time ago there was a link to external portal where we could update NS. Right now, I see no option in my App Service Domain to access this portal and with created Azure DNS Zone, I cannot change nameservers.